# Find a circle $O_{\rho}(0)$ containing all the roots of polynomial $z^{4} - 4z + 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Given polynomial
$$z^{4} - 4z + 1$$

How can I find the radius of the circle in which all of its roots lie? I was trying to find the exact forms of the roots, but it's too complicated.

Comment: Rouche's theorem proves that there is one root $|z|<1$ and there are $4$ roots $|z|<2$

Comment: Sure it's a quartic equation so you can get the complete expressions for the roots, but it is too difficult to actually find the modulus of the roots : Rouche is your best bet.

Comment: Using Rouche's theorem, I can find the number of roots in a given area. I'm not quite understand what to do next.

Comment: @Loh is that not sufficient to solve your problem?

Comment: I know the number of roots, and I want to find the circle in which it lie. Should i solve the inverse problem?

Comment: @Loh: Presumably the problem is to find (with proof) _some_ circle containing all the roots, not necessarily a _smallest_ circle. Thus if you can show that the circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$ contains $4$ roots, then that circle qualifies.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$If $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root of $z^4-4z+1$, then $|z| < 2$.

**Proof:**

Suppose instead that we have $z^4-4z+1=0$ and $|z| \ge 2$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
z^4-4z+1=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^4-4z=-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(|z|)(|z^3-4|)=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2(|z^3-4|)\le 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|z^3-4|\le {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|z^3|-4\le {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
8-4\le {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{align*}
contradiction, which validates the claim.

Comment: A bit shorter: $1 = \left| \frac{4z-1}{z^4}\right | \le \frac{4}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^4} = \frac{9}{16} < 1$. – It is also not difficult to show that $|z| < 5^{1/3} \approx 1.7$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, that gives a larger bound.

The companion matrix of this polynomial is

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 4 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Using [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), its eigenvalues (i.e., the roots of your polynomial) lie in the union of the disks $D(O,1)$ and $D(O,5)$, that is in $D(O,5)$. This means for all root $z$, $|z|\le5$.

Note that in this case (because the coefficient of $z^3$ is zero), this is equivalent to the [Lagrange bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange%27s_and_Cauchy%27s_bounds): given a polynomial $a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$, its roots $z$ all must satisfy $|z|\le\max(1,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|\frac{a_k}{a_n}\right|)$.

Comment: Given that you [voted to close the question as “low quality”](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1522888) I am a bit surprised that you answer it :)

Comment: @MartinR I agree. I voted to close in review. However, I retracted my vote. I just found annoying to use Rouché when there are many other simpler bounds: Gershgorin is a heavy weapon, but Lagrange and Cauchy bounds are classics. The question is certainly of poor quality, but it would be nice for MSE to have a similar (better) question, to show different way to achieve this.